# SQL - After Update Trigger - How to add timestamp when column value changes to specific Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I want create a Trigger to update the column

```
dbo.tbl_dispatching.Actual_Pickup_Time
```

with timestamp when the below column is updated to 5

```
dbo.tbl_dispatching.Status_ID = "5"
```

And update

```
dbo.tbl_dispatching.Actual_Delivery_Time
```

with timestamp when the below column is updated to 8

```
dbo.tbl_dispatching.Status_ID = "8"
```

I have done this so far and not sure how to complete it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Delay_Timestamp ON [dbo].[tbl_dispatching] 
FOR UPDATE
AS
    declare @DispatchingID int; --Primery Key of Dispatching_ID
    declare @Statusid int;
    declare @Actual_Pickup_Time datetime;
    declare @Actual_Delivery_Time datetime;
    declare @audit_action varchar(100);

select @DispatchingID=i.dispatching_id from inserted i; --Primery Key of Dispatching_ID
select @Statusid=i.Status_ID from inserted i; 
select @Actual_Pickup_Time=i.Actual_Pickup_Time from inserted i; 
select @Actual_Delivery_Time=i.Actual_Delivery_Time from inserted i;   

if @StatusID = (5)
    set @Actual_Pickup_Time=GETDATE();
if  @StatusID = (8)
    set @Actual_Delivery_Time=GETDATE();

update set tbl_Dispatching(Actual_Pickup_Time,Actual_Delivery_Time) 
values (@Actual_Pickup_Time,@Actual_Delivery_Time) where dispatching_id = @DispatchingID
go
```

would this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fundamental flaw is that you seem to expect the trigger to be fired **once per row** - this is **NOT** the case in SQL Server. Instead, the trigger fires **once per statement**, and the pseudo tables `Inserted` and `Deleted` might contain **multiple rows**.

In such a case, this assignment

```
select @Statusid=i.Status_ID from inserted i;
```

will pick *one, arbitrary row* from the `Inserted` table and **ignore all other rows** - typically not what you want.

You need to rewrite your trigger in a **set-based** fashion - don't expect `Inserted` and `Deleted` to contain only a single row - they won't !

You need to use code something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Delay_Timestamp ON [dbo].[tbl_dispatching] 
FOR UPDATE
AS
    -- Update Actual_Pickup_Time if "Status_ID" has changed to 5
    UPDATE disp
    SET Actual_Pickup_Time = SYSDATETIME()
    FROM dbo.tbl_Dispatching disp
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON i.DispatchId = disp.DispatchId  -- use PRIMARY KEY of table!
    INNER JOIN Deleted d ON d.DispatchId = disp.DispatchId  -- use PRIMARY KEY of table!
    WHERE
          i.Status_ID = 5         -- new value is 5 
          AND d.Status_ID <> 5    -- old value was NOT 5

    -- Update Actual_Delivery_Time if "Status_ID" has changed to 8
    UPDATE disp
    SET Actual_Delivery_Time = SYSDATETIME()
    FROM dbo.tbl_Dispatching disp
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON i.DispatchId = disp.DispatchId  -- use PRIMARY KEY of table!
    INNER JOIN Deleted d ON d.DispatchId = disp.DispatchId   -- use PRIMARY KEY of table!
    WHERE
          i.Status_ID = 8         -- new value is 8 
          AND d.Status_ID <> 8    -- old value was NOT 8
```